# Vue js with rxjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rxjs

Is there a conflict that I could be unaware of with vue and rxjs. I am running vue 2 and trying to implement a debounce function. with these imports:

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
```

I have both vue and rxjs installed with vue-rx plugin.

It is telling me that I need to install from event with npm like this

```
 npm install --save rxjs-compat/add/observable/fromEvent
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I installed rxjs but it says I need to install rxjs-compat/add/observable/fromEvent

Comment: So, install it?

Comment: Well you can't Could not install from "rxjs-compat/add/observable/fromEvent" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Comment: Please add this erro message to your question.

Comment: rxjs 6 is a bit different to rxjs 5, which means depending on how you're importing, `rxjs-compat` may be necessary

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

In the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/compat), it is mentioned that this package is needed for fixing compatibility issues.

Comment: Why do I need to install it in the first place?